# android: standby button, the touch locks and the phone remains active

Tags: android, touch, standby

I would like to make an application when it is activated by pressing the standby button, the touch locks and the phone remains active . Which method should I use to do this and to take control of the standby button?

Comment: block with the touch dispachtouchevent () except that I would touch that you do disable the standby button and the screen stays on (I just used the wakelock just press the Standby button the phone goes into standby)

Answer (score 0):

> Which method should I use to do this and to take control of the standby button?

Fortunately, this is not supported by Android, for obvious security reasons. Apps could use this to prevent people from turning off their phones, for example.

Comment: I want to use the on / off button just to lock the touch, and from that moment to keep the screen active. can you do?

Comment: @user1026063: AFAIK, SDK applications are not informed about the power button press.